# How to separate comma separate values and get aggregate of a column in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a `table T1` as  below

```
product_id val
123,567    5
999        4
999        3
```

and another **table T2**,

```
t_product_id // this maps to product_id in above table
123
999
```

In the final output, for t_product_id in  table T2 I have to get value for it from T1. For duplicate product_ids (999) I want to get the min value, and for 123 I want to get 5

This is how output should look like

```
product_id  value
123         5
999         3
```

My query ->

```
select t1.product_id, min(t1.value)
from T1 t1
group by t1.product_id
```

I am not sure what needs to be done next. How to separate comma separated values and check if 123 from T2 exists in T1 and get the value for it

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: `t_product_id` is unique in `table T2` ?

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible to keep only one product_id per row in table T1?
I think this would simplify matters for you. T1 would be:

```
123 | 5
567 | 5 
999 | 4 
999 | 3
```

Use join to only select the ids that exist in T2

```
select t1.product_id, min(t1.value)
from T1 t1 join T2 on (t1.product_id = t2.t_product_id)
group by t1.product_id
```